# T-SQL Programming Return table based on Variable

Tags: sql, t-sql, adventureworks

I've been trying to make this work for a while now but I can't figure what's wrong.

The function needs to return a table based on the input date. If the input year is not available in the database, the function needs to return the data for all the years, otherwise, it needs to return the data only for the specified year.

Maybe someone here can help.
I'm using the 2014 AdventureWorks Database.

Thanks

```
CREATE FUNCTION DBO.udf_fonction(@year INT)

RETURNS TABLE

AS

RETURN 

IF @year IN (SELECT DISTINCT(YEAR(OrderDate)) AS Years
         FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader)

(
    SELECT YEAR(A.OrderDate) AS SalesYear,
    C.Name AS SalesTerritory, 
    D.Name AS SalesCountryName, 
    CASE(A.OnlineOrderFlag)
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Online'
        WHEN 0 THEN 'In-store'
    END AS SalesType,
    SUM(A.SubTotal) AS Montant

    FROM sales.SalesOrderHeader A
    INNER JOIN Sales.Customer B ON A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory C ON B.TerritoryID = C.TerritoryID
    INNER JOIN Person.CountryRegion D ON C.CountryRegionCode = D.CountryRegionCode
    WHERE YEAR(A.OrderDate) = @year
    GROUP BY YEAR(A.OrderDate), C.Name, D.Name, CASE(A.OnlineOrderFlag)
                                                    WHEN 1 THEN 'Online'
                                                    WHEN 0 THEN 'In-store'
                                                END
                                                )
ELSE (SELECT YEAR(A.OrderDate) AS SalesYear,
    C.Name AS SalesTerritory, 
    D.Name AS SalesCountryName, 
    CASE(A.OnlineOrderFlag)
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Online'
        WHEN 0 THEN 'In-store'
    END AS SalesType,
    SUM(A.SubTotal) AS Montant

    FROM sales.SalesOrderHeader A
    INNER JOIN Sales.Customer B ON A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory C ON B.TerritoryID = C.TerritoryID
    INNER JOIN Person.CountryRegion D ON C.CountryRegionCode = D.CountryRegionCode
    GROUP BY YEAR(A.OrderDate), C.Name, D.Name, CASE(A.OnlineOrderFlag)
                                                    WHEN 1 THEN 'Online'
                                                    WHEN 0 THEN 'In-store'
                                                END
                                                )
GO
```

Comment: The RETURNS clause defines a local return variable name for the table returned by the function. The RETURNS clause also defines the format of the table. The scope of the local return variable name is local within the function.

The Transact-SQL statements in the function body build and insert rows into the return variable defined by the RETURNS clause.

When a RETURN statement is executed, the rows inserted into the variable are returned as the tabular output of the function. The RETURN statement cannot have an argument.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: It's not exactly what you're asking for, but you could just do the main query with your where statement as:

    WHERE YEAR(A.OrderDate) = @@year OR @@year IS NULL  (it won't let me use one @ sign, just fix that part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE YEAR(A.OrderDate) = @year 
   OR not exists (select 1 from sales.SalesOrderHeader where YEAR(OrderDate) = @year)
```

You are not returning a table anywhere